# Is a differentiable function required to have at least one point where its derivative is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ there be a real-valued differentiable function everywhere in the interval $]a,b[$.

Does $\frac{df}{dx}$ need to be continuous somewhere in the interval $]a,b[$? Or can a differentiable function $f$ exist so that $\frac{df}{dx}$ is continuous nowhere in the interval $]a,b[$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n ( f(x+1/n) - f(x) )$$

This is the limit of continuous functions and thus Baire class $1$, that is, it is the pointwise limit of continuous functions.

A theorem states that a pointwise limit of continuous functions can only have discontinuities at a meagre set and thus must be continuous on a dense set of points.

Comment: You're essentially saying that $f'(x)$ can have discontinuities so long that the discontinuities in $f'(x)$ form a nondense set? 

Does that imply that $f'(x)$ has to be continuous somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the set of points at which $f'(x)$ is discontinuous must be the countable union of nowhere dense sets.  This *can* be a dense set, but its complement must also be dense, so the points of continuity must be dense.

Comment: @NSERCProtester To learn more, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function